# yii : How to setup different setting for different date picker at a single form?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

Problem : the application has 2 or more date picker. They are defined by id and name. And their date setting should not be same.

e.g exchange rate date should be today date only. And ETA complete date should not be today date.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                'name'=>'Request[exchange_date]',       
                'model'=>$model,
                'value' => $model->exchange_date,
                'i18nScriptFile' => 'jquery.ui.datepicker-ja.js', // (#2)
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'id' => 'Request_exchange_date',
                    'size' => '10',
                ),
                'defaultOptions' => array(  // (#3)
                    'showOn' => 'focus', 
                    'dateFormat' => 'dd-M-yy',
                    'showOtherMonths' => true,
                    'selectOtherMonths' => true,
                    'changeMonth' => true,
                    'changeYear' => true,
                    'showButtonPanel' => true,
                    'yearRange'=>'0:+1', 
                    //'minDate'=> 0,
                )
            ));

$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                'name'=>'Request[eta_date]',        
                'model'=>$model,
                'value' => $model->eta_date,
                'i18nScriptFile' => 'jquery.ui.datepicker-ja.js', // (#2)
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'id' => 'Request_eta_date',
                    'size' => '10',
                ),
                'defaultOptions' => array(  // (#3)
                    'showOn' => 'focus', 
                    'dateFormat' => 'dd-M-yy',
                    'showOtherMonths' => true,
                    'selectOtherMonths' => true,
                    'changeMonth' => true,
                    'changeYear' => true,
                    'showButtonPanel' => true,
                    'yearRange'=>'0:+1', 
                    'minDate'=> 0,
                )
            ));
```

Q : How can I be setup different setting for different date picker at single form?

Comment: And you have something done? What did U try to do it?

Comment: yes I changed 'yearRange'=>'0:+1', 
                    'minDate'=> 0, to many setting in both date picker. but it is working the last setting. e.g if I comment  the Request_exchange_date->mindate = 0 and if I set Request_eta_date->mindate = 0, it is working mindate = 0 in both date picker.

Comment: Do U add some validation for this fields? And also, do U set client validations?

Comment: only yii rules. I didn't add any other external validation by js.

Comment: And what do you want? what difference in datepickers field you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set 'options' instead of 'defaultOptions' while using CJuiDatePicker. by using 'defaultOptions' you are forcing all other instances of date picker to behave the same.